# Detecting shape location and heading with opencv

Tags: opencv, video, computer-vision, vision

**Background**

I'm working on a cheap & simple method for tracking robots in their environment, avoiding gps, encoders, etc. There will be multiple robots aiming to reach a target area (see basic example below), and the computer should be feeding them data on their location, heading and target. [image: example]

**Approach**

I've decided to use a camera looking top-down onto the test area, coupled with coloured shapes (e.g. arrowhead) on top of the robots, and use OpenCV to detect their position and orientation in successive frames from the video.

Ideally there would be a fairly continuous stream of location and orientation data for each robot, however I've worked with OpenCV before and realise it can take time. An update rate around (or better than) 1Hz would be acceptable (i.e. lower frame rate/not using all frames).

I've used OpenCV before to SIFT filter frames from a video, and detect features to create a mosaiced image from the frames. However I'm finding it difficult to adapt my current knowledge to this specific problem, and online research has not really helped with an easy way to detect orientation.

**Question**

What is the easiest method that can detect a shape's location and orientation in an image quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect). You can take [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) as reference. By doing this, you will get fitted rectangles for your each object and then you can use the mid points of the rectangle edges to get the angle.

**Note:** *There will be two angles for each fitted rectangle so you should create an algorithm to choose the correct one for your situation.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this was the approach I initially had in mind, but the two possible solutions for each rectangle were what put me off. What sort of algorithm are you suggesting to rectify this?

Comment: @S.Dunnim If we talk about the triangles in your image, you can make an algorithm according to short edge and long edges of rectangles. For rotation data, *minAreaRec* is a very precise method, I used  it many times in my projects

Comment: Thanks, to clarify I can see how to use minAreaRect to obtain two possible angles of orientation. I'm just unsure how to choose which is the correct one? For the most part, I can use the  most recent angle as a reference angle, and choose the new angle closest to the reference - but how do I choose at the start of the process with no reference angle? Or when the arrow turns through 12 o'clock and the 2 new possible angles are equally close to the reference angle? Cheers

Comment: @S.Dunnim what do you mean by *reference*? I probably misunderstand you before. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Ah sorry. As I understand, minAreaRect method will give 2 possible angles the object could be oriented at. The problem is deciding which is correct. For most of the robot's movement, this is easy, as it will be whichever angle is closest to the previous angle (the 'reference' angle). However when deciding on the very first angle, there is no previous ('reference') angle to compare it to...